# Vuejs 3 and Bootstrap 5 Modal Reusable Component Show Programmatically

Tags: typescript, vue-component, vuejs3, bootstrap-5

Tring to create a (semi) reusable Modal Component based on Bootstrap 5,with vuejs 3 and composible API. Managed to get it partially working,
Given (Mostly standard Bootstrap 5 modal, but with classes being added based on 'show' prop, and slots in body and footer):

```
<script setup lang="ts">
defineProps({
  show: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    default: "<<Title goes here>>",
  },
});
</script>

<template>
  <div class="modal fade" :class="{ show: show, 'd-block': show }"
    id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">{{ title }}</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <slot name="body" />
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <slot name="footer" />
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
            Close
          </button>              
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

and being 'called' by

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue";
import Modal from "@/components/Common/Modal.vue";

let modalVisible= ref(false);

function showModal(){
 modalVisible.value = true;
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="showModal">Show Modal</button>
  <Modal title="Model title goes here" :show="modalVisible">
    <template #body>This should be in the body</template>
    <template #footer>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Extra footer button</button>
    </template>
</Modal>
</template>
```

I get a modal 'shown' but the fade in animation doesn't work ,and the backdrop isn't visible, and the data-bs- buttons in the modal don't work ( i.e. it won't close). I feel its something to do with my whole approach.

[image]

NOTE. I cannot use a standard button with `data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal"` attributes as the actual trigger of this model comes from the logic of another component (as in just setting a bool), and the reusable modal component will be independent of its trigger --- it also doesn't feel the proper 'Vue' way to do it.

So I think I'm just 'showing' the html, and I need to instantiate a bootstrap modal somehow... just not sure how to do it

package.json (well the relavant ones)

```
"dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.31",
  },
```

[Code sand box here](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-dream-uufdjs) (Couldn't get the new Composition API and TS with  working on code sandbox, so its a slight re-write with the standard options API approach, so code is slightly different, but exibits the same behaviour)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

OK.. so a few more hours I came up with a solution, posting here as it may help others.
The bootstrap modal 'Object' needs to be created. So first had to import the modal object from bootstrap. Its creation needed a DOM reference, so had to add a `ref` to the html element, and a `ref` prop in the script to hold the link to it.
The DOM references in Vue aren't populated until the component is mounted so the construction of the Bootstrap modal object needs to be done in Onmounted as the `ref` will now link to the actual DOM element.
Then instead of passing a show prop down, as making this keep in sync between parent and child was cumbersome, I just exposed a `show` method on the dialog component itself (also feels a bit more elegant). Since `<script setup>` objects are [`CLOSED BY DEFAULT`](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose), the exposure of the method is done via `defineExpose`.. and we now all [disco](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=UkSPUDpe0U8#t=11s)

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted, ref } from "vue";
import { Modal } from "bootstrap";
defineProps({
  title: {
    type: String,
    default: "<<Title goes here>>",
  },
});
let modalEle = ref(null);
let thisModalObj = null;

onMounted(() => {
  thisModalObj = new Modal(modalEle.value);
});
function _show() {
  thisModalObj.show();
}
defineExpose({ show: _show });
</script>

<template>
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby=""
    aria-hidden="true" ref="modalEle">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">{{ title }}</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <slot name="body" />
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <slot name="footer"></slot>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
            Close
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

and the 'parent'

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue";
import Modal from "@/components/Common/Modal.vue";

let thisModal= ref(null);

function showModal(){
 thisModal.value.show();
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="showModal">Show Modal</button>
  <Modal title="Model title goes here" ref="thisModal">
    <template #body>This should be in the body</template>
    <template #footer>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Extra footer button</button>
    </template>
</Modal>
</template>
```

.. probably should additionally should add an OnUnmount to clean up the object to be tidy.

Comment: I have "bootstrap": "^5.2.0" and I get this `thisModal.value.Show is not a function`

Comment: Nvm. I copied exactly your code. The `thisModal.value.Show();` has big 'S'.

Comment: @Shulz yeah minor case typo .. have corrected.. cheers

Comment: that's really handy, thanks (saved me even more hours i reckon!)

Comment: I know that this thread is old, but, one question though, how did you handle the closing of the modal? For example if you are to use this modal for login and if the login is successful, modal closes but the backdrop still remains.

Comment: @RichardC.Alvarez Surprised its doing that. Once the modal is constructed, the elements that have the `data-bs-dismiss` attribute should fully close the modal and remove the backdrop. Additionally in the example above I only exposed a show, you could additionally expose a close... that you could call just to be sure.

Comment: @OJay thank you for your reply. clicking on an element with data-bs-dismiss closes the modal completely along with its backdrop. in my case, i used the modal as a login form. upon successful authentication, page will be redirected to another page and it's working well. Only issue is that the modal backdrop remains after page redirect.

Comment: @RichardC.Alvarez as mentioned, probably because the login button your adding in the footer template, which runs your login code, doesn't have a data-bs-dismiss on it... or expose a close on the modals exposures, and execute the modal.close on the click handler of your login button.

Comment: @OJay, adding data-bs-dismiss on submit closes the modal even if auth attempt has failed. Following your suggestion, exposing close works best. Thank you so much for your help and guidance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using TS but it can easily be converted into TS. Make sure you keep the Accessibility features (focus trap, esc to close the modal, aria attributes) !!! This is how I did it. The only thing I would change is the backdrop animation it's a bit sloppy. (Also i included a simple utility to generate unique ID's).

Children:

```
<template>
  <teleport to="body">
    <focus-trap v-model:active="active">
      <div
          ref="modal"
          class="modal fade"
          :class="{ show: active, 'd-block': active }"
          tabindex="-1"
          role="dialog"
          :aria-labelledby="`modal-${id}`"
          :aria-hidden="active"
      >
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document" >
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title text-dark" :id="`modal-${id}`"><slot name="title"></slot></h5>
              <button
                  type="button"
                  class="close"
                  data-dismiss="modal"
                  aria-label="Close"
                  @click="$emit('closeModal', false)"
              >
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body text-dark">
              <slot></slot>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer text-dark">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @click="$emit('closeModal', true)">Yes</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" @click="$emit('closeModal', false)">No</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </focus-trap>
    <div class="fade" :class="{ show: active, 'modal-backdrop show': active }"></div>
  </teleport>
</template>

<script>

import { ref, watch} from 'vue'
import IdUnique from '../js/utilities/utilities-unique-id';
import { FocusTrap } from 'focus-trap-vue'

export default {
  name: 'Modal',
  emits: ['closeModal'],
  components: {
    FocusTrap: FocusTrap
  },
  props: {
    showModal: Boolean,
    modalId: String,
  },
  setup(props) {
    const id = IdUnique();
    const active = ref(props.showModal);

    watch(() => props.showModal, (newValue, oldValue) => {
      if (newValue !== oldValue) {
        active.value = props.showModal;
        const body = document.querySelector("body");
        props.showModal ? body.classList.add("modal-open") : body.classList.remove("modal-open")
      }
    },{immediate:true, deep: true});

    return {
      active,
      id
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Parent:

```
<template>
  <div class="about">
    <div v-for="product in products">
      <Product :product="product" :mode="mode"></Product>
    </div>
  </div>
  <template v-if="mode === 'cart'">
    <div class="hello">
      <modal :showModal="showModal" @closeModal="handleCloseModal">
        <template v-slot:title>Warning</template>
        <p>Do you really wish to clear your cart</p>
      </modal>

      <button href="#" @click="handleToggleModal">{{ $t('clearCart') }}</button>
    </div>
  </template>
</template>

<script>
import {ref} from "vue";
import Product from '../components/Product'
import Modal from '../components/Modal'

export default {
  name: 'HomeView',
  components: {
    Product,
    Modal
  },
  setup() {
    const mode = ref('cart');
    const showModal = ref(false);
    let products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products'));
    
    const handleClearLocalstorage = () => {
      localStorage.clear();
      location.reload();
      return false;
    }

    const handleCloseModal = (n) => {
      showModal.value = false;
      if(n) {
        handleClearLocalstorage();
      }
    }

    const handleToggleModal = () => {
      showModal.value = !showModal.value;
    }

    return {
      handleClearLocalstorage,
      handleCloseModal,
      handleToggleModal,
      showModal,
      mode,
      products
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Unique Id:

```
let Id = 0;

export default () => {
    return Id++;
};
```

Comment: Beutifull hack `{ show: active, 'd-block': active }`can be used on modal for boolean manual maintainess

Comment: luck of animation here