# How to handle modal close with InertiaJS form onSuccess?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

Good day everyone. I'm currently working on a Laravel project. I'm using laravel/breeze VueJS with Inertia. Now, with this project, Login is done using bootstrap modal component. Validation and authentication works well the only issue that I'm facing is that, when successful authentication happens, modal should close and it does but backdrop remains.

One thing that I notice is that the form onSuccess does not execute any emit function. I tried using console.log and it does works.

Please see the code below for reference...

Header.vue

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import Modal from '@/Components/Modal.vue'

let thisModal = ref(null)

function showModal() {
    thisModal.value.show()
}

function closeModal() {
    thisModal.value.close()
}
</script>

<template>
    <header class="shadow-sm">
        <Modal v-if="! $page.props.auth.user" ref="thisModal">
            <template #body>
                <Login @closeParent="closeModal" @showParent="showModal" />
                <Register />
            </template>
        </Modal>
    </header>
</template>
```

Modal.vue

```
<script setup>
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue'
import { Modal } from 'bootstrap'

defineProps({
    title: String
})

let modalEle = ref(null)
let thisModalObj = null

onMounted(() => {
    thisModalObj = new Modal(modalEle.value)
})

function _show() {
    thisModalObj.show()
}

function _close() {
    thisModalObj.hide()
}

defineExpose({ show: _show, close: _close })
</script>

<template>
    <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" ref="modalEle">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header bg-secondary">
                    <slot name="header" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body tab-content py-4">
                    <slot name="body" />
                </div>
                <slot name="footer" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Login.vue (This is where form is located)

```
<script setup>
import { Link, useForm } from '@inertiajs/vue3'
import Checkbox from '@/Components/Checkbox.vue'
import InputError from '@/Components/InputError.vue'
import InputLabel from '@/Components/InputLabel.vue'
import PrimaryButton from '@/Components/PrimaryButton.vue'
import TextInput from '@/Components/TextInput.vue'
import PasswordToggle from '@/Components/PasswordToggle.vue'

defineProps({
    canResetPassword: {
        type: Boolean,
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
    },
})

const form = useForm({
    email: '',
    password: '',
    remember: false,
})

const emit = defineEmits()

const submit = () => {
    form.post(route('login'), {
        onFinish: () => form.reset('password'),
        // onBefore hides the modal
        onBefore: () => emit('closeParent'),
        // onError shows the modal
        onError: () => emit('showParent'),
        // Use onSuccess instead
        onSuccess: () => emit('closeParent') // <- This should be the most efficient and user friendly
    })
}
</script>

<template>
    <form @submit.prevent="submit" id="login-tab" class="tab-pane fade show active" autocomplete="off" novalidate>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <InputLabel for="email" value="Email" />
            <TextInput
                id="email"
                type="text"
                name="email"
                v-model="form.email"
                autofocus
                autocomplete="username"
            />
            <InputError class="fs-sm" :message="form.errors.email" />
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <InputLabel for="password" value="Password" />
            <PasswordToggle>
                <TextInput
                    id="password"
                    type="password"
                    v-model="form.password"
                    autocomplete="current-password"
                />
            </PasswordToggle>
            <InputError class="fs-sm" :message="form.errors.password" />
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3 d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between">
            <div class="form-check mb-2">
                <Checkbox id="remember" name="remember" v-model:checked="form.remember" />
                <InputLabel for="remember" value="Remember me" />
            </div>
            <Link v-if="$page.props.app.canResetPassword" class="fs-sm" :href="route('password.request')">
                Forgot password?
            </Link>
        </div>
        <PrimaryButton class="btn-shadow d-block w-100" :disabled="form.processing">
            <span v-if="form.processing" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm me-2" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span v-else class="me-2"><i class="ci-unlocked"></i></span>
            {{ `Sign in` }}
        </PrimaryButton>
    </form>
</template>
```

As you can see, I'm sending emit from Login.vue to call close or show from Header.vue. On the current code, modal is hidden when Sign in button is click and will be shown again if an error occurs like validation or invalid account credentials. I want it to only close when authentication is successful but, again, it seems that emit is not being executed using onSuccess. I think the issue lies with the fact that onSuccess is receiving an Inertia response from the controller as shown below:

AuthenticatedSessionController.php

```
/**
 * Handle an incoming authentication request.
 */
 public function store(LoginRequest $request) // : RedirectResponse
 {
     $request->authenticate();

     $request->session()->regenerate();

     return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
  }
```

By the way, the modal code here is an answer provided by [@OJay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1478987/ojay) on this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71461086/7515652)

Answer (score 0):

Been doing a lot of testing and still got no proper or best way to handle this issue. I've decided to avoid using api and stick with Inertia response/redirects. To resolve the `modal's backdrop still remains after successful login redirect` issue, I decided to manually remove the modal backdrop on modal parent update event.

1. If login is successful, a redirect response is fired.

   return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);

This causes the page to be redirected to home page without properly closing the modal form which leads to modal backdrop covering the whole page.

1. To resolve this, I added code that checks the `body` tag for modal classes and entire document for `<div class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div>` along with a body style attribute of `style="margin-bottom: 8px; overflow: hidden; padding-right: 0px;"`
2. Once modal is open, bootstrap updates the body tag class to `<body class="handheld-toolbar-enabled modal-open">` along with the style attribute to `style="margin-bottom: 8px; overflow: hidden; padding-right: 0px"` it then adds a new element `<div class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div>`
3. Taking note of these, I came up with a solution that removes and updates these items which is triggered by modal parent's onUpdated event. The code is as follows

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onUpdated } from 'vue'
// Get the document's body tag
const body = ref(document.body)

// Function to check and update body tag
const checkAndModifyBody = () => {
    const modalOpenClass = 'modal-open'
    const expectedStyle = 'margin-bottom: 8px;'
    const modalBackdropSelector = 'div.modal-backdrop.fade.show'

    if (body.value.classList.contains(modalOpenClass)) {
        body.value.classList.remove(modalOpenClass)
    }

    if (body.value.style.cssText !== expectedStyle) {
        body.value.style.cssText = 'margin-bottom: 8px;'
    }

    const modalBackdrop = body.value.querySelector(modalBackdropSelector)
    if (modalBackdrop) {
        modalBackdrop.remove()
    }
}

// Watch for changes and run the checkAndModifyBody function
watch(body, () => {
    checkAndModifyBody()
});

// Initial check
onUpdated(() => {
    checkAndModifyBody()
})
```

This is a dirty solution and not very vue-ish way to handle things.

Thank you everyone and if anybody have a better way of doing things please do let me know.

Cheers!